# Android Bluetooth LE API onScanResult ScanRecord bytes meaning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I am developing an app which scans for beacons in range and displays beacons' data to the user. I am using Android Bluetooth LE API. In `onScanResult()` method I get `ScanResult` object which I then parse to raw bytes. This is a sample of what I get from one of my beacons:

```
02:01:06:1A:FF:4C:00:02:15:74:27:8B:DA:B6:44:45:20:8F:0C:72:0E:AF:05:99:35:00:00:00:01:C5:02:0A:00:08:16:F0:FF:64:00:00:00:01:11:09:4D:69:6E:69:42:65:61:63:6F:6E:5F:33:36:38:35:30:00:00
```

I had no problems with finding out what the first part mean - it corresponds to the iBeacon format:

```
02:01:06:1A:FF:4C:00:02:15 - iBeacon prefix
74:27:8B:DA:B6:44:45:20:8F:0C:72:0E:AF:05:99:35 - UUID
00:00 - Major
00:01 - Minor
C5 - TX power
```

But I have completely no idea what the rest of the bytes are. Are these some kind of manufacturer specific data or what? Can they be used to get any useful information?

```
02:0A:00:08:16:F0:FF:64:00:00:00:01:11:09:4D:69:6E:69:42:65:61:63:6F:6E:5F:33:36:38:35:30:00:00
```

Comment: Here's a good explanation of scan frame format: https://github.com/alt236/Bluetooth-LE-Library---Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/uk/co/alt236/bluetoothlelib/device/adrecord/AdRecord.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth packets are broken down into what are called PDUs.  A PDU starts with a one byte length followed by a one byte type.  The interpretation of the remaining bytes is specific to the PDU type.

Some of that extra data is of interest (mainly the Bluetooth name) but most of it is not.

So these bytes mean:

02:0A:00
(Flags PDU.  Not of much interest.)

08:16:F0:FF:64:00:00:00:01
(Service Data PDU.  Service UUID: FFF0, Service Data: 64:00:00:00:01)

11:09:4D:69:6E:69:42:65:61:63:6F:6E:5F:33:36:38:35:30
(Complete Local Name PDU: "MiniBeacon_36850")

00:00
(Buffer fill)

Comment: What is actually Service Data PDU? What do these bytes mean?

Comment: The bytes are arbitrary and specific to the implementation.  They can mean anything that the broadcaster wants them to.    To understand the meaning, you'd have to ask the beacon manufacturer.

Comment: Quick side-question: Is there some PDU in the message you analyzed which informs the receiver that this is a scan-response? And if so which PDU is it and how do you analyze it to figure out that's it's a scan-response. @davidgyoung

Comment: Please post as its own question and I am happy to respond